# want to pass variable from template tool kit file to cgi script

Tags: perl, cgi, argument-passing, template-toolkit

i am having the code in the template tool kit file :

```
<html>
 <head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0;
function addNew() {
// Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
// Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
// Create a new text input
var newText = document.createElement('input');
newText.type = "input";
//newText.value = counter;
// Create a new button input
var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
newDelButton.type = "button";
newDelButton.value = "Delete";
// Append new text input to the newDiv
newDiv.appendChild(newText);
// Append new button input to the newDiv
newDiv.appendChild(newDelButton);
// Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
// counter++;
// Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
newDelButton.onclick = function() {
mainContainer.removeChild(newDiv);
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body >
<form name="group_save" method="post" action="process.cgi">
<div id="mainContainer">
<div><input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addNew()"></div>
</div>
 <div><input type = "submit" value = "Save"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the value of the text box to the cgi file process.cgi to insert that into database .

code in the process.cgi :

```
my $grupsave = $cgi->param("group_save");
if ($grupsave =~ /^([-\@\w.]+)$/) {
    $grupsave = $1;
} else {
    die "Bad data for OS('$grupsave') in group";
}

if($grupsave ne '')  {
    my $grupsave_insert = $dbh->do (q{INSERT INTO group_management  (group_name,group_description,isactive) VALUES (?,?,?)}, undef, ($grupsave,'','y'));
} else {
}
```

but on checking, I have found that the value s not getting in the process page.
please help me to fix this.

Comment: What text area? There's no text area in your HTML. You have two inputs - a button and a submit.

Comment: Not the text area....i am having the text box, it will be created on java script call.I will also add the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

You get the parameter with this code:

```
my $grupsave = $cgi->param("group_save");
```

But there is no HTML input in your form with the name "group_save". The text input that you create using Javascript has no name, so its contents aren't passed on to your CGI program.

You need to give the text box the name "group_save".